# Open source Eclipse plugin for bit bucket

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server, ibm-integration-bus

Working in IBM integration bus. We are maintain code in bit bucket repository using source tree.

Which eclipse plugin (open Source) we can use to fetch the code from bit bucket code repository ?

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here. However, a popular plug-in to work with Git repositories in Eclipse is EGit: https://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the egit.

Refer this link- http://crunchify.com/how-to-configure-bitbucket-git-repository-in-you-eclipse/